# Getting crash report (NegativeArraySizeException) by google libraries caused

Tags: android, firebase, admob, android-support-library

I don't know why users are getting this error. But its the biggest issue in firebase crash reporting. If anyone knows how to fix this issue or why its happening, I'll be very grateful. Thank you.

```
Exception java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -520103681
    fw.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:323)
    fw.c (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:541)
    fw.d (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:563)
    fx.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:404)
    fw.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:157)
    es.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:84)
```

I'm getting this crash report from all api levels (from 21 to 25)

build.gradle file: (all google libraries)

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not the right place for Firebase problem reports.  If you're seeing some unexplained problem that you think is caused by a Firebase SDK, contact Firebase support directly: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting

Comment: Ok but I don't know is this problem related with Admob or play-services or any other support library?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same exception and found that The problem is not in the App-level build.gradle file but it's in the Project-level build.gradle file.

When I added my android app to the firebase project, one of the steps was to add the following classpass in the Project-level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  // Add this line
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

After some time Android studio highligted indicating that there is a new version available (4.3.3) and when I updated the classpass, Android studio keep displaying the Exception java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException when I try to run the app on an Emulator win Android 7 (API 24) but when I tried another Emulator with Android 4.4 (API 19), android studio doesn't display the exception and the application runs normally.

So the solution for my case was to rollback this line from

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

to

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`

I hope this answer could help some other developers.